# Scroll bar not showing up in android app

Tags: android, scroll, titanium

I am using Titanium for creating my Android app. I have a one big form in my window. But the scrollbar is not showing up there. I think its not set by default in Titanium. So I just want to know is there any way for the scrollbar to show up.

Comment: What component are you using? Where do you want to show ScrollBar. Are you using ScrollView or ScrollableView. More details can help us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `showVerticalScrollIndicator` or `showHorizontalScrollIndicator` so setting the one you want to true will make the scroll bar show up.